# Batch Insert not Inserting

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have been trying to insert a "batch" of data into a SQLITE db in an Android application. I am getting no errors, but when trying to select from that Table later, no data is returned.

The application uses both SQL server and SQLITE since the device wont always be connected to the network it cannot access SQLServer all the time, so I am running a query to select from SQLServer and then I pass that resultset to the method that is meant to push the data to the SQLITE DB

The process flow I am following is as follows:

1. Delete everything currently in the sqliteDB

   ```
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();    
    mDb.execSQL("delete from TABLE_1");
   ```
2. Get data from SQLserver

   ```
   Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
   connect = con;


   try {

       PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("Exec SelectAll '" + Param1+ "'");
       rs = statement.executeQuery();

       liteAdapter.insertIntoDbLite(rs);

       con.close();
   } catch (SQLException ex) {

       String error = ex.getMessage();

   }
   ```
3. Pass resultset from step 2 to the method that should batch insert the data to sqlite

   ```
   //Insert Records into Bale Table from SQL Server
   public void insertIntoDbLite(ResultSet rs)
    {
     mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     mDb.beginTransaction();
     try {

       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       try {
           while (rs.next()) {

               //put value(Column_Name, record)
               values.put("COL1", rs.getString("Col1_Val"));
               values.put("COL2", rs.getString("Col2_Val"));
               values.put("COL3", rs.getString("Col3_Val"));
               values.put("COL4", rs.getString("Col4_Val"));
               values.put("COL5", rs.getString("Col5_Val"));
               values.put("COL6", rs.getString("Col6_Val"));
               values.put("COL7", rs.getString("Col7_Val"));
               values.put("COL8", rs.getString("Col8_Val"));
               values.put("COl9", rs.getString("Col9_Val"));

           }
           mDb.insert("TABLE_1", null, values);
       }
       catch (java.sql.SQLException e)
       {
           Log.e("Error in SQL",e.toString());
       }

       mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
   }

   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       Log.e("Error in transaction",ex.toString());
   }
   finally
   {
       //End the transaction
       mDb.endTransaction();
   }

    }
   ```

so it all seems to run fine, but when I later query the db and to a select, no values are returned from this table, 
am I missing something or just doing it wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `getReadableDatabase` = wonder what `readable` means ? Does that mean you can delete?

Comment: `String error = ex.getMessage();` How about actually printing this error?

Comment: to be honest, I am not really sure, punching a bit above my weight with android and java, but since there was data and there now no longer is data, I assumed it worked. (terrible I know)

Comment: For a start print the error message

Comment: Change `mDb.insert("TABLE_1", null, values);` to `Log.d("INSERT","Return from insert is " + Long.toString(mDb.insert("TABLE_1", null, values)));`. If value in log  is -1 then row wasn't inserted if positive then that's the rowid of the inserted row, showing that the insert worked. If nothing in Log, then while loop is being entered.

Comment: Use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) bro , It'll solve all your problems.

Comment: @MikeT thanks, so the it returned 1 so the row was inserted, seems my problem may lie elsewhere then. thanks.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, added the print for the error message, but like I said, I wasn't getting any errors. (using android studio, and debugged, so was stepping through code and saw that it was never entering the catch) but yes, shouldn't swallow exceptions, so thanks for that.

Comment: @user7592671 perhaps add the table definition to the question. Perhaps a constraint is causing the issue. Try `insertOrThrow` instead of insert.

Comment: @ScaryWombat getReadable will moslty get a Writeable DB as per *Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk, requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a read-only database object will be returned.* [getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29)

Comment: @MikeT Thanks for this info

Comment: Thanks guys, So the issue wasn't with the Insert. turns out there was a truncate issue so that made my where clause value "invalid", meaning when I queried the SQLitedb, it returned 0 records because the value I was querying wasn't in the DB. 
the Log.d was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be nothing glaringly wrong with the given code. The likely scenario is that the update is in not performing the update due to a constraint (a rule such as, but not limited to NOT NULL, UNIQUE). Another, perhaps less likely scenario is that the while loop isn't being entered.

You could distinguish which by changing

```
mDb.insert("TABLE_1", null, values);
```

to

```
Log.d("INSERT","Return from insert is " + Long.toString(mDb.insert("TABLE_1", null, values)));
```

This will then either write output with :-

- (a) no output to the log indicating that the while loop was not entered, so **rs** is empty.
- (b)  -1 being the sole value(s) returned, indicating that the update is not being done due to constraints.
- (c) with all or some positive (> 0) value(s) returned, this would indicate, that the updates are being performed and that the issue is likely with the method used to checked the data later.

If (b) then changing `mDb.insert` to `mDb.insertOrThrow` should result in the first exception being caught which should indicate the issue.